# May a person with a nature of getting angry be a dayan?

Tags: halacha, rabbis, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, beit-din-court, psych-mentalhealth

I sit in a *beis din* with a *dayan* who gets angry very easily. He can't seem to control his anger, causing great anguish to the litigants, and a big *chilul Hashem* at times. I have been asked to approach the *av beis din* to complain, and I would like to make a solid *Halachic* case.

So:

**Can someone who cannot control his anger be a *dayan*?**

I'd appreciate *Halachic* grounds and sources regarding the prerequisite of a *dayan* to be in control of his emotions and outbursts.

Comment: Why don't you ask your musmach

Comment: @sam I think he's the musmach, the person who gave smicha is a somech or something like that.

Comment: You are right it's really masmich

Comment: Being a dayan is an awesome responsibility (see, for e.g., [*Sanhedrin* 7a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=7&format=text) that a judge must cultivate a feeling of reverence and dread for his job). Part of that responsibility is being extremely patient with the people whom you are charged to help (Rambam, [*Hil. Sanhedrin* 25:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=14457), אזהרה לדיין שיסבול את הצבור כאשר ישא האומן את היונק; see also ibid. ch. 20-25). If you are not confident that you can function thusly as a dayan, you should speak to your own rebbi for counsel.

Comment: Additionally, there are many ways you can apply your knowledge of *Choshen Mishpat* aside from judging in a *beis din*. You can help people who have relevant halachic questions about which you are knowledgeable. You can write *sefarim*. You can give *shiurim*. You have accomplished an impressive feat by learning *Choshen Mishpat*, and you now have much to offer even aside from in a judicial capacity.

Comment: I wish you'd rephrase the question. I was in the middle of writing what i think is a pretty good answer when it got closed.

Comment: I also find it hard to believe someone who has yadin yadin and cannot find an answer themselves in this inyun

Comment: ok chevrah. this was a rhetorical question, hence i dont have a masmich and im not a musmach. I do sit in a beis din with such a dayan and have been asked to approach the roash av beis din to complain, and i wold like to make my case. hence its on topic and most of the comments were in place but don't help us

Comment: i rephrased the question. thank fred for the amazing mareh mokom and user6591 i'm waiting to see your words of wisdom

Comment: Is it just anger or is it gavaah as well

Comment: sources in torah view gavah and caas as being in the same group. a humble person doesn't get angry. anger is always about the I I I.

Comment: rabbi, the manner in which the question is phrased still sounds like it's seeking a personal psak, because it's asking about a *specific person*. If you edit the question to merely be about the general case ("Can someone who cannot control his anger be a dayan?") then I'd vote to reopen

Comment: I sit in a beis din with a dayan who gets angry very easily and have been asked to approach the roash av beis din to complain, and i wold like to make my case. He can't seem to control his anger this causes great anguish to the misdaynim, and a big chilul hashem at times I'd appreciate Halachic grounds and sources regarding the prerequisite of a dayan to be in control of his emotions and outburst.

Comment: I stood before such a _bes din_ this past _erev Rosh Hashana_ morning. I hope my _n'darim_ are annulled!

Comment: It says in סימן ז - מי ראוי לדון,  that  י דַּיָּן שֶׁיּוֹדֵעַ בַּחֲבֵרוֹ שֶׁהוּא גַּזְלָן אוֹ רָשָׁע, אֵין לוֹ (יט) לְהִצְטָרֵף עִמּוֹ. and Chazal tell us that anger is like idol worship, making him a Rasha.

Comment: @DannySchoemann, source the second statement, and you have an answer.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - הלכות דעות 2:3 - no time left today.

Answer (score 2):

Lets ignore all mussar and the horrible things Chazzal say about anger. Let us also ignore that humility is one of the seven qualities a judge needs. And we will also ignore the chillul Hashem that can come out from a judge behaving like a child.

Instead I will quote the one source I think may shed some light on this, but keep in mind your situation is not explicitly mentioned.

The Shulchan Aruch in Choshen Mishpat siman 7 siff 8 writes 'Two talmidei chachamim that hate each other are not allowed to sit on a court case together. Due to the animosity between them, each one will put his mind to undo the others words.'

This is not a psul in the judgement bidieved, but the language used  lichatchila is a strong one of psul.
The important thing to remember is that in laws such as this, the qualification for hate is to have not spoken to each other in three days, out of this animosity.

The Aruch Hashulchan in siff 17 adds  'and the outcome of the ruling will not be true. Also do not appoint two people who's personalities are different in their nature and dealings (seffer hachinuch).

The common theme is that what we've got here is a failure to communicate, which translates as a psul, lichatchila at least, for judges who need to be able to communicate with one another and the litigants. An angry, argumentative person disrupts the system of justice from being carried out to its truthfulness. Especially if his outbursts cause the other judges and or the litigants from speaking their mind.

Disclaimer: I'm not certain the psul mentioned applies to ZaBL'A and a case of pshara krova l'din. But the idea as least seems to hold up.